# Are any known problems complete for $P$ under "$O(1)$ reductions?"

Tags: complexity-theory, polynomial-time, constant-time

The usual many-one reduction involves Turing machines transforming an input, $w$, of some language to an input, $f(w)$, of some other language in polynomial time. (Where $w \in L_1 \iff f(w) \in L_2$).

But for $P$-completeness, logspace or NC reductions are often used instead (taken from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-complete)), as using polynomial time reductions would allow every problem in $P$ to be complete, besides the empty language and the full language.

But there is a stronger reduction, the "$O(1)$" reduction. Transforming an input $w$ to $f(w)$ in constant time. Are there any known problems that are complete for $P$ under these reductions? If there are, are they known?

As noted by John L in the comments, the specific model of Turing machine must be defined, as not all models are equivalent by a constant factor. Because I am looking for the strongest reduction, I am refering to single-tape one directional TM's when I am talking about reduction.

I am beginning to think that a reduction like this doesn't exist under many-one reductions, from [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/159649/how-do-turing-machines-output-fw-for-o1-reductions) question I asked. So I think broadening the scope of this question to Turing reductions that run in constant time is beneficial.

Comment: "Transforming an input $w$ to $f(w)$ in constant time." You may want to define the exact model of computation when you refer to "constant time". The usual polynomial-time-reduction completeness is well-defined without mentioning a particular model of computation, since the differences among models of computation by most Turing machines (TMs) such as one-tape one directional TMs or multiple-tape  bidirectional TMs are subsumed by the polynomial factor. It looks $O(1)$-time-reduction completeness depends on the kind of TMs, as well as how the input are encoded to be put on the TMs.

Comment: @JohnL. Good point. I am looking for the strongest possible reduction, so I will edit my question to include "single-tape one directional Turing machine."

Comment: Check this: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/159613/does-textttdtimeo1-contain-only-finite-languages. Languages for which $O(1)$ time gives anything useful are very limited.

Comment: An O(1) reduction couldn't even access the whole input. As the problem size got bigger the reduction could edit a smaller and smaller portion of the problem, tending to zero. So it seems any such reducible problem would have to be in some sense "almost identical" to the P-complete problem, or would be an O(1) problem itself that could be replaced with constant-size "yes" or "no" solution to the P-complete problem

Comment: A reasonable definition of "O(1) reduction" is [AC0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC0) reduction, where AC0 is *parallel* O(1) time. See also <https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/92856/what-does-ac0-many-one-reduction-mean>.